# GPU and RAM frequency from the Android filesystem

Tags: android, gpu, frequency, ram

I would like to know how to read de GPU and RAM operation frequency from the Android filesystem. I know that I can obtain the CPU frequency from files such as:

```
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_max_freq
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq
```

I'm trying to do that with Pandaboard, but in fact I need to do it in more development boards (Odroid-PC, Beagleboard-xM, Sabreboard and Wandboard).

Any idea? at least how to do that with an app? I tried with CPU-z but it do not has this information. Also, I tried with commands such as dumpsys without success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use omapconf for the TI families (Panda) - refer https://github.com/omapconf/omapconf. It gives all the information about the system you would need.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works for Panda ('./omapconf trace perf' says that GPU runs at 153MHz). Now I need some similar to others kits, but it was useful to me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

On Pandaboard, using busybox, I search:

```
root@android:/ # busybox find . | busybox grep gpu
```

The result:

```
./sys/kernel/debug/clock/virt_38400000_ck/sys_clkin_ck/dpll_per_ck/dpll_per_x2_ck/dpll_per_m7x2_ck/gpu_fck
./sys/kernel/debug/clock/virt_38400000_ck/sys_clkin_ck/dpll_per_ck/dpll_per_x2_ck/dpll_per_m7x2_ck/gpu_fck/flags
./sys/kernel/debug/clock/virt_38400000_ck/sys_clkin_ck/dpll_per_ck/dpll_per_x2_ck/dpll_per_m7x2_ck/gpu_fck/rate
./sys/kernel/debug/clock/virt_38400000_ck/sys_clkin_ck/dpll_per_ck/dpll_per_x2_ck/dpll_per_m7x2_ck/gpu_fck/usecount
```

And I can see the gpu frequency with:

```
cat ./sys/kernel/debug/clock/virt_38400000_ck/sys_clkin_ck/dpll_per_ck/dpll_per_x2_ck/dpll_per_m7x2_ck/gpu_fck/rate
```

On Pandaboard, running GFXBench it says

```
307200000
```

And when GFXBench is not running:

```
153600000
```

What matches with the OMAP 4430 user guide (PER_SGX_FCLK = 307,2MHz or 153,6MHz).

The file **usecount** change from 0 to 1 when gpu change from 153,6 to 307,2 MHz.

I hope to found something similar with others kits.